# Update record error : "Unique constraint violation found" in magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, controllers

In the controller, I am inserting and updating data.
But when record is already exist it's not update it's again try to insert so i am getting above error:

```
if(!$checkoutPrescriptionCollection->count()) {
 $checkoutPrescription->setQuoteId($quoteId);
 $checkoutPrescription->setCustomerPrescriptionId($prescription);
 $checkoutPrescription->save();
}
else{
   $checkoutPrescription->load($quoteId,'quote_id');
   if($checkoutPrescription->getPrescriptionQuoteId()){
    $checkoutPrescription->setCustomerPrescriptionId($prescription);
    $checkoutPrescription->save();
    }
}
```

In xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/*
 * Copyright © 2019 vendor. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details
 */
-->
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table comment="Customer Prescption Quote Table" engine="innodb" name="vendor_prescription_quote" resource="default">
        <column comment="Prescription Quote Id" identity="true" name="prescription_quote_id" nullable="false" padding="10" unsigned="true" xsi:type="int"/>
        <column comment="Quote Id" name="quote_id" nullable="false" padding="10" unsigned="true" xsi:type="int"/>
        <column comment="Prescription Id"  name="customer_prescription_id" nullable="false" padding="10" unsigned="true" xsi:type="int"/>
        <constraint referenceId="PRIMARY" xsi:type="primary">
            <column name="prescription_quote_id"/>
        </constraint>
       <!-- <constraint xsi:type="foreign" referenceId="CUSTOMER_PRESCRIPTION_ID" table="vendor_prescription_quote" column="customer_prescription_id" referenceTable="customer_prescription" referenceColumn="customer_prescription_id"/> -->
    </table>
</schema>
```

Comment: can you show error screenshot and installSchema.php file ?

Comment: @MohitRane please check

Comment: you didn't mention constraint for `quote_id` and `customer_prescription_id`

Comment: what are you using to insert/modify data, model or factory ?

Comment: I had done the same in my module, i can make my answer useful if you could post your code.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add foreign key constraint for **`quote_id`** and **`customer_prescription_id`**

Refer this link

> **https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html**

```
<constraint xsi:type="foreign" referenceId="FL_ALLOWED_SEVERITIES" table="declarative_table" column="severity" referenceTable="severities" referenceColumn="severity_identifier" onDelete="CASCADE"/>
```

Comment: why need to give foreign key reference ? it should be update right?

Comment: are you using quote_id as reference to Magento default table?

Comment: yes but i am updating only customer_prescription_id

Comment: you're also setting the `$quote_id` value,  `$checkoutPrescription->setQuoteId($quoteId);`